# Detect / Determine data stored in a varbinary field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several tables a varbinary column in a database. They have names like CSB_BLOB or OBJECT_BLOB. Now I am having intermittent success with getting the data out.

For example this query returns readable text from this data. GREAT!

```
0x46726F6D3A20226465616E6E6167726.....etc --data as stored in the column

SELECT CAST(CSB_BLOB AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Message' FROM OBJECT_BLOB
```

However this column has the following query results.

```
0x0001000000FFFFFFFF01000000000000000C....etc. --data as stored in column

--this query returns empty result
SELECT (CSB_BLOB AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Message' FROM CSB_STATUS_LOG

--this query returns no change???
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CSB_BLOB, 2), 2) FROM CSB_STATUS_LOG
0001000000FFFFFFFF01000000000000000C....etc
```

Obviously there is a difference between the two but I am not educated enough to interpret this difference. What do I need to learn / read so I can look at the data in one of these BLOB columns and know how to convert it to something meaningful?

If you can't really know just from looking what are all the different conversion I need to try? That in and of itself seems like an impossible question since just about anything can be converted to binary and stored so....

As far as the different conversion I am not asking you to write my TSQL for me but instead just tell me the common conversions.

Something like:

1. Try to cast as varchar to see if it is text.
2. Turn into a byte array and see if it is a jpg
3. Turn into a byte array and see if it is a pdf
4. Convert it to hex and then cast as varchar
5. etc....

Thank You

Comment: Do you know if it holds files? If you do then check out [Export to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992254/sql-server-2008-r2-best-way-to-export-blob-and-other-column-data-out-to-the-fil)

Comment: You are certainly not going to know if it is a jpg in TSQL.  Your best bet is to return a binary and then perform analysis in a programming environment like .NET.